# No more zombies in Redcliffe

Tags: dragon-age-origins

[Original title: *We don't go to Redcliffe any more*. Changed, alas, to something actually descriptive.]

So, I'm trying to defend Redcliffe from the zombie horde coming out of the castle. Unfortunately, I've killed all of the zombies that I can see, and no more seem to be coming, but the NPCs seem to think that something still needs to happen. I can go up to the area where the green mist is, all the way to the castle gate, but I can't go through, and there aren't any obvious plot markers or triggers that I still need to hit. Is this a bug, or did I miss something?

Comment: have you checked the whole village. Sometimes a zombie hangs somewhere in the town and requires a killing for the quest to complete.

Comment: check down past the smith and on the docks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong, but I had to reload from a save in order to fix it.

At the start of the battle by the windmill, I moved forward very quickly, before the oil barrels had a chance to light. This caused the barrels *not* to light, since I was in their area of effect at the time, which evidently borked the other triggers for the rest of the scene.

Moral of the story: sit tight and let the zombies come to you.

Comment: In case you were wondering, you can choose (via dialog options) not to light the oil drums. Just wondering if you were relying on that behavior to prevent the drums from lighting.

Comment: @sykora, when you say "dialog options", do you mean by talking to one of the NPC leaders before the battle? Obviously you can avoid having the barrels light by not getting the oil in the first place, or by not telling Sir Perth about it, but were you referring to something else?

Comment: Find the oil, tell Ser Perth about it, then tell him it was a bad idea when he suggests that you light them. He'll realize that they're more likely to burn you than the zombies.

Answer (score 3):

I had that happen before, search the entire zone for stray zombies that got stuck.

My stray zombie was in the lower part of the town, you know when you go down that hill to the campfire with the guards defending it, keep going straight and to the right around the houses, that's where mine is. I have also heard of zombies getting stuck in the mist on the top part, and the left side of the camp fire as you go down the path.

Basically search every nook and cranny of the zone. It's not very big, so you'll find it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I had a Zombie get stuck somewhere I could not reach him and had to reset the battle.  It is not unheard of that Zombies bug out and make the fight impossible.